# How to find the difference between dates, which are based on conditions from previous rows

Tags: sql, oracle, date, plsql

Here is my Table:

```
CREATE TABLE ABC
 (
     nekey NUMBER(5), 
     seq number(20),
     task varchar2(10), 
     status varchar2(10),
     entrydat date, 
     findat DATE
  );
```

Values:

```
insert into ABC (nekey, seq, task, status, entrydat, findat) values (1, 3, 'Build', 'Closed', 
to_date('08-01-2019', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), to_date('08-04-2019', 'mm-dd-yyyy'));

insert into ABC (nekey, seq, task,status, entrydat, findat) values (1, 6,'Paint','Open', null, 
null); 

insert into ABC (nekey,seq,  task,status, entrydat, findat) values (1, 9,'Assemble','Pending', null, 
null);

insert into ABC (nekey,seq, task,status, entrydat, findat) values (2, 3,'Build', 'Closed',
to_date('08-02-2019', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), to_date('08-05-2019', 'mm-dd-yyyy'));

insert into ABC (nekey,seq, task, status,entrydat, findat) values (2, 6,'Paint', 'Closed',
to_date('08-05-2019', 'mm-dd-yyyy'), to_date('08-09-2019', 'mm-dd-yyyy')); 

insert into ABC (nekey,seq, task, status,entrydat, findat) values (2,9, 'Assemble', 'Open', null, 
null);
```

Now I want to get the OutPut as follows:

For every Key, The Tasks are ordered in the following Order.

1) Build

2) Paint

3) Assemble. ((But my data has more than 20 tasks) I have used these 3 as an example)

So, I have to calculate the "days" column as shown in the image attached.

So when

1) the status is closed then findate- entrydate

2) When status is Open or Null then (sysdate - Findate of the **previous task** ) ( I have already solved the case where first task is Open, it is projectstartdate - entrydate)

3) When Status is Pending then no calculation

How do I do this in Oracle SQL,

[image]

Comment: We can solve the problem as you posted it, but that may not be enough for your real-life problem. Specifically: you say you have 15 different "tasks", and it seems they are totally ordered. What gives that order? Do you have a "tasks" table, where each task is shown, with its order in the sequence? If so, it would help to post a small sample too (in this case, a small table with three rows for the three tasks, and two columns for "task name" and "seq_num" (sequence number).

Comment: Also, what if the FIRST task has OPEN status? Then there is no FINDATE of the previous task; should that FINDATE be considered NULL (in which case the difference from SYSDATE is also NULL)?

Comment: Yes I can modify the question,

Comment: I already solved the case where the first task is Null, I just Subtract the ProjectStartDate - Entrydate

Comment: Please run your CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements (in a test schema where you can recreate the table from scratch), and debug them until they work. There are a number of mistakes in your statements.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=740d7a489b4dca4ce80b85d0331727f0 Fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements have numerous errors in them. In particular, the INSERT statements create five rows with NEKEY = 1, but your output shows three rows with NEKEY = 1 (and three with NEKEY = 2). The output shown below is based on fixing all the errors in your statements, AND changing the NKEY in two of the INSERT statements to match your output.

The answer to your question is the `case` expression in the `select` clause, using the analytic `lag()` function where needed. For status OPEN on the first row for a NEKEY, this query will return NULL. In an Answer to me under your original post, you said that you are able to take care of that yourself (but you mentioned expressions that don't appear anywhere in your post, so I left that out - for you to fix, probably using an NVL(...) call).

```
select abc.*, 
       case status when 'Closed'  then findat - entrydat
                   when 'Pending' then null
                   else trunc(sysdate) - lag(findat) 
                                           over (partition by nekey order by seq) 
       end as days
from   abc
;

     NEKEY        SEQ TASK       STATUS     ENTRYDAT   FINDAT           DAYS
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          3 Build      Closed     08/01/2019 08/04/2019          3
         1          6 Paint      Open                                     22
         1          9 Assemble   Pending                                    
         2          3 Build      Closed     08/02/2019 08/05/2019          3
         2          6 Paint      Closed     08/05/2019 08/09/2019          4
         2          9 Assemble   Open                                     17
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=740d7a489b4dca4ce80b85d0331727f0 I ll try it here

Comment: Hi @mathguy, I also wanted to know if I could subtract findates. For Example: When sequence not in 3 and status is closed then (8/9/2019 - 8/5/2019)  that is 4

Comment: @StackOne - I don't understand your last question.  Isn't that what my solution does already?

Comment: I figured out my answer to my previous question: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7fbeed473f3bf658b8a2edd62c141875 is attached